# Guidance Regarding Filtering of Listpicker

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have 4 ListPickers with HeaderName(categories of computer accessories).

1. Processor.
2. Motherboard.
3. RAM.
4. HardDrive.

   Categories.XAML.CS

   ```
   public Categories()
   {
       InitializeComponent();
       this.DataContext = new manufactuers();
   }

   private void processorListPicker_SelectionChanged(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
   {
       processorListPicker.GetBindingExpression(ListPicker.SelectedItemProperty).UpdateSource();
   }

   private void motherboardListPicker_SelectionChanged(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
   {
       motherboardListPicker.GetBindingExpression(ListPicker.SelectedItemProperty).UpdateSource();
   }

   private void harddriveListPicker_SelectionChanged(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
   {
       harddriveListPicker.GetBindingExpression(ListPicker.SelectedItemProperty).UpdateSource();
   }

   private void ramListPicker_SelectionChanged(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
   {
       ramListPicker.GetBindingExpression(ListPicker.SelectedItemProperty).UpdateSource();
   }
   ```

Categories.XAML

```
        <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <toolkit:ListPicker x:Name="processorListPicker" Header="Processor"
            ItemsSource="{Binding List1, Mode=TwoWay}"
            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem1, Mode=TwoWay}" 
            SelectionChanged="processorListPicker_SelectionChanged" Width="360" Margin="54,106,42,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        <toolkit:ListPicker x:Name="motherboardListPicker" Header="Motherboard"
            ItemsSource="{Binding List2, Mode=TwoWay}"
            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem2, Mode=TwoWay}"
            SelectionChanged="motherboardListPicker_SelectionChanged" Width="360" Margin="54,191,42,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        <toolkit:ListPicker x:Name="harddriveListPicker" Header="HardDrive"
            ItemsSource="{Binding List3, Mode=TwoWay}"
            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem3, Mode=TwoWay}"
            SelectionChanged="harddriveListPicker_SelectionChanged" Width="360" Margin="54,282,42,240" Height="85" />
        <toolkit:ListPicker x:Name="ramListPicker" Header="RAM"
            ItemsSource="{Binding List4, Mode=TwoWay}"
            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem4, Mode=TwoWay}"
            SelectionChanged="ramListPicker_SelectionChanged" Width="360" Margin="54,0,42,155" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Height="85" />
    </Grid>
```

manufactures.cs  -  ViewModel

```
public class manufacturers
{
    public manufacturers()
    {
        // MUST Initialize the selected items
        SelectedItem1 = "INTEL";
        SelectedItem2 = "ASUS";
        SelectedItem3 = "WESTERN DIGITAL";
        SelectedItem4 = "CORSAIR";
    }

    private IEnumerable<string> manufacturersList
    {
        get
        {
            return new[]
               {
                   "INTEL",
                   "AMD",
                   "WESTERN DIGITAL",
                   "CORSAIR",
                   "SEAGATE",
                   "ASUS",
                   "SAMSUNG",
                   "TOSHIBA",
                   "KINGSTON",
               };
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> List1
    {
        get
        {
            return manufacturersList;
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> List2
    {
        get
        {
            return manufacturersList;
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> List3
    {
        get
        {
            return manufacturersList;
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> List4
    {
        get
        {
            return manufacturersList;
        }
    }

    public string SelectedItem1 { get; set; }
    public string SelectedItem2 { get; set; }
    public string SelectedItem3 { get; set; }
    public string SelectedItem4 { get; set; }
}
```

Now when the user clicks on any of these LISTPICKERS, for example user select PROCESSORS-LISTPICKER, all vendors that manufacture processor should be displayed in the LISTPICKER ITEMS.

Note: Suppose we have list of manufactures which can be displayed either from the viewmodel or online parsing the XML or the HTML.

Comment: http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/listpicker-for-wp7-in-depth

Comment: Thanks for replying @Derek Beattie, I already visited this web but not getting any help in my scenario.

Comment: Sir @Matt Lacey, question is now Edited & i think this time it is more clear. Kindly help me and let me know if u still not understand the question.

Comment: I still don't see a question. All you're doing is stating what you want to happen. If your question is actually "This is what I want, how do I do this?" then say so and show what you've tried. What specific part is causing the problem?

Comment: Sorry Sir, @Matt Lacey, now you can check what i basically need.

Comment: Right, we understand the scenario, but not what isn't working. There's no *question* here.  "I've tried X, but Y is not working.  What am i missing?"  Stackoverflow is **not** rent-a-coder!

Answer (score 1):

This is something that is new to me, as I am not a seasoned programmer, so I can't give you code, so I would have to research how to build it, but the way I would do it is to have the controls bound to a view model, and have that view model send back to the UI using INotifyPropertyChanged.  Bind the buttons (I assume buttons, since you said click them), to commands in the view model, and the view model uses that event to return the correct list to the ListBox.

I'm actually trying to teach myself MVVM right now, otherwise I would not have a clue to even make the suggestion.

Comment: thanks @hopmedic for replying, but i m not getting your point.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm not understanding the question:

xaml:

```
 <Controls:ListPicker Header="Processor:"
                             ItemsSource="{Binding ProcessorMfgs}"
                             Margin="0,499,0,-499" />
```

in ViewModel:

```
  private List<string> _processorMfgs;
        public List<string> ProcessorMfgs
        {
            get { return _processorMfgs; }
            set
            {
                _processorMfgs = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => ProcessorMfgs);
            }
        }

    ProcessorMfgs = new List<string>
                                {
                                    "Intel", "AMD"
                                };
```